# Кнопка "Добавить в корзину"

Tags: python, django

Делаю интернет-магазин на django. Не понимаю как реализовать кнопку добавить в корзину.
Скажем есть модель товара. И модель корзины, где хранятся заказаные товары.
На странице выводятся модели телефонов таким образом:

```
<div class="modelList">
            {% for model in model_list %}
                <div class="model">
                    <div class="modelImage">
                        <img src="{% static 'images/model.jpg' %}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="discription">
                        <div class="modelName">{{ model.name}}</div>
                        <div class="modelDiscription">
                            {{ model.description}}
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <div class="colors">

                        </div>
                        <div class="price">{{ model.price }} р.</div>
                        <button>Добавить в корзину</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

Как сделать чтобы кнопка при нажатии отправляла товар в коризну?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, рекомендую избавится от модели корзины в пользу модели покупки:

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User)     # Кто купил
    item = models.ForeignKey(Goods)        # Что купил
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField()  # Сколько купил
    ... # И другие нужные поля. Например, когда купил.
```

Такую модель легче расширять в дальнейшем, легче строить по ней отчёты и т.д.

Во-вторых, в шаблоне сделать что-то вроде `<a href="{% url 'basket:add' model.pk %}">Добавить в корзину</a>`

Наконец в view:

```
def add_to_backet(request, item_id):
    item = Goods.objects.get(pk=item_id)
    Purchase.objects.create(customer=request.user, item=item, count=1)
```

Это только скелет для примера, его надо доработать!